# Lookup an action in Vim by name

Tags: vim

I'm looking for an equivalent Vim command to Emacs M-x.That is, looking up actions (like w) by name in case I don't remember the key bindings.

Is there any way to do this in Vim?

Comment: Im not sure vim has names for everything? What do you even call the `w` action?

Comment: @FDinoff Well, not sure either. I've just seen that feature in Emacs and I thought I was a very nice one. Sublime Text does something similar with Cmd+P+Something and I just felt jealous :-)

Comment: A good starting place `:h quickref`. You can use `:helpgrep` to find more obscure things.

Comment: :map would list all your current key bindings. You can also reference your .vimrc for custom bindings.

Comment: The terms "action" and "key binding" suggest that you are looking for something that vim does not have.  It has several different modes, and some of those modes (primarily Normal and Command-line) have commands.  I think that @PeterRincker's pointers are good ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course Vim does command-line completion.

```
:w<C-d>
```

lists all the commands that start with `w` and

```
:w<Tab><Tab><Tab>
```

takes you through the whole list one item at a time.

[image: :w<C-d>]

You can put the following line in your `~/.vimrc` to enable the "wildmenu" and read `:help wildmode` for further refinements:

```
set wildmenu
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The w command has name w. You can call it like this

```
:normal w
```

You can combine this with "execute". It enables you run commands from register or variable

```
:execute "normal w"
:execute @a
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to search for all actions starting with 'w' for example.

Comment: Oh, that's complicated. You can build a great amount of such commands. Consider vi", vi(, vi),...  Than the same with vaX ...

Answer (score 0):

For auto completion tab works for me.

For finding previously used (but forgotten) commands: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history

For a new command use `:help:`.